# defining new monad instance

Tags: haskell, monads, deriving, derivingvia

A few days ago I was trying to prove monad laws by creating a new monad instance but I found myself stuck at defining the new monad instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, InstanceSigs #-}
import Control.Monad

newtype Test a = Test { getTest :: [Maybe a] }
  deriving Functor

instance Applicative Test where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = liftM2 ($)

instance Monad Test where
  return :: a -> Test a
  return a = Test $ [Just a]
  
  (>>=) :: Test a -> (a -> Test b) -> Test b
  g >>= f = concat (map f g)  --Tried to do something like this
```

I tried something following the list monad definition, but is stuck because concat expects [[a]] but here it gets [Test b], so maybe there are other functions available or is there a way to make concat work on the newType? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `type` aliases, `newtype` wrappers need to be manually applied and removed. Replace `g >>= f = concat (map f g)` with `Test g >>= f = Test $ concat (map (getTest . f) g)`.

This will leave you with only one more type error: `g` has type `[Maybe a]` instead of the needed `[a]`. We can tack on a `catMaybes` (needs `import Data.Maybe`) to take care of that: `Test g >>= f = Test $ concat (map (getTest . f) $ catMaybes g)`. Now it compiles.

Unfortunately, this instance isn't lawful. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to establish why not, and whether it can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 0):

They can be [derived the](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) the [`MaybeT []`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) transformer:

```
{-# Language DerivingVia              #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Control.Applicative       (Alternative)
import Control.Monad             (MonadPlus)
import Control.Monad.Fix         (MonadFix)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..))
import Control.Monad.Zip         (MonadZip)
import Data.Kind                 (Type)

type    Test :: Type -> Type
newtype Test a = Test { getTest :: [Maybe a] }
 deriving (Functor, Foldable, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadFail, MonadFix, MonadPlus, MonadZip)
 via MaybeT []
```

[`:instances MaybeT []`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances):

```
>> :instances MaybeT []
instance [safe] GHC.Base.Alternative (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Applicative (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Functor (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Monad (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] GHC.Base.MonadPlus (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Data.Functor.Classes.Eq1 (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Foldable (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Data.Functor.Classes.Ord1 (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Data.Functor.Classes.Read1 (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Data.Functor.Classes.Show1 (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Traversable (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] MonadFail (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Control.Monad.Fix.MonadFix (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Control.Monad.Zip.MonadZip (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Monad (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Applicative (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
instance [safe] Functor (MaybeT [])
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe’
```

Some of these instances can also be derived via [`Compose [] Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) but famously monads don't compose. [`:instances Compose [] Maybe`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances):

```
>> :instances Compose [] Maybe
instance Alternative (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Applicative (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Functor (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Foldable (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Eq1 (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Ord1 (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Read1 (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Show1 (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Traversable (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Compose’
instance Alt (Compose [] Maybe) -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Alt’
instance Hashable1 (Compose [] Maybe)
  -- Defined in ‘hashable-1.3.0.0:Data.Hashable.Class’
```